# Dynamic send with multiple methods and parameters

Tags: ruby

How could I dynamic regex parsing with method

#### Current method

```
@product.price = line.gsub(/,/, '').scan(/\d{3,9}/).first
@product.model = line.rm_dirty.split("：").last.strip
@product.location = line.split("：").last.strip
```

#### Expected method # pass the string operations to another function

However, I alway got `` NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub(/,/, '')' `` for

```
def fetch_by_keyword_and_regex(regex_str)
  @line.send(regex_str)
end

fetch_by_keyword_and_regex("gsub(/,/, '').scan(/\d{3,9}/).first")
```

Comment: What is `regex_str` normally like?

Comment: Your second code block only contains the `@product.price` part, what about `model` and `location`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make this more dynamic you can send in a block:

```
line_sub = lambda { |line|
  line.gsub(/,/, '').scan(/\d{3,9}/).first
}
```

Then you can use this on anything:

```
line_sub.call(@line)
```

This is a lot like JavaScript declaring `var line_sub = function(line) { ... }`.

The `send` method only allows making a particular method call by name:

@line.send(:sub, /,/, '').send(:scan, /\d{3,9}/).send(:first)

That's something you could express in an array, like:

```
line_process = [
  [ :sub, /,/, '' ],
  [ :scan, /\d{3,9}/ ],
  [ :first ]
]
```

Then use that like:

```
line_process.inject(@line) do |obj, args|
  obj.send(*args)
end
```

This is quite a mess, so I'd avoid it whenever possible. Ruby's block-passing semantics are a lot cleaner for metaprogramming.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use one of Ruby's evaluation functions, i.e. `eval`, `instance_eval` or `instance_exec`, but that's not recommended.

I would `yield` the object instead: (assuming that your actual implementation / use case is more complex)

```
def fetch(regex_str)
  yield @line
end

fetch { |l| l.gsub(/,/, '').scan(/\d{3,9}/).first }
```

Comment: @tadman just like the OP's `fetch_by_keyword_and_regex`. I suppose the actual implementation is more complex.

Comment: I see what you're doing now, but an `attr_accessor` might be more convenient in practice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, I question the approach altogether.  Reasons:

1) metaprogramming should be done as a last resort, when less obtuse approaches fail to satisfy the need,

2) the variable stuff in question is code/functionality, and should be expressed as such -- expressing it as a string and then eval'ing it, etc., is redundant and overly complex, and

3) this approach will, to some extent, conceal to the human reader, and definitely to the code editor, analysis tool, etc., what is really going on.

One alternative approach would be a hash whose keys are the attribute names, and values are the code to apply to the values, essentially a lookup table for attribute processing functionality, e.g.

```
ATTRIBUTE_PROCESSORS = {
  price:    ->(line) { line.gsub(/,/, '').scan(/\d{3,9}/).first },
  model:    ->(line) { line.rm_dirty.split("：").last.strip },
  location: ->(line) { line.split("：").last.strip }
}
```

...and call it like this:

```
ATTRIBUTE_PROCESSORS[:price].(line)
```

A side benefit of this is that all your attribute processing is colocated, so you can easily spot duplication, and refactor as appropriate.